# List Number of Exact Strings in a File

Tags: grep

```
  11111  1  11  1111111    1 1  1  1 1 1 1  111 1  1 1  1  11 11111111   1    11 1 11 11  1 11111   1 1
```

I have a file as shown but on a larger scale. My goal is to output the amount of 111s, 1s, 11s, 1111s, ect. are in the file. I seen many posts talking about doing:

```
grep "\^word\" text_file
grep "\bword\b" text_file
grep -Fx "word" text_file
and so on...
```

All of those have either outputted nothing or the entire file. What should I do to list just the certain numbers?

Comment: show the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tr`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | sort | uniq -c
   1
  17 1
   5 11
   1 111
   2 11111
   1 1111111
   1 11111111
```

This gives you a count for one empty lines as well (the first line in the output above), but you can avoid that with `sed`:

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | sed '/^$/d' | sort | uniq -c
  17 1
   5 11
   1 111
   2 11111
   1 1111111
   1 11111111
```

The pipeline changes all spaces to newlines, sorts the resulting lines and counts the number of occurrences of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with grep for this one but with awk:

```
$ a="11111  1  11  1111111    1 1  1  1 1 1 1  111 1  1 1  1  11 11111111   1    11 1 11 11  1 11111   1 1"

$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) ++seen[$i]}END{for (k in seen) print k,"found:"seen[k]}' <<<"$a"
1 found:17
11 found:5
111 found:1
11111 found:2
1111111 found:1
11111111 found:1
```

This single line demo should work with your whole file (replace `<<<"$a"` with `yourfile`)